# How to add a jar file to a java rest api project?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, glassfish, jersey

I have a very simple REST API which uses jersey 2.x (Glassfish). It works when I do nothing but output *hello world* string.
but when I add a few jars and use them in 1 line of code it throws lots of class `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors. I get no compile or syntax errors. The error is very long so excuse me if i posed lots of rubbish in it.

I see lots of solution to this problem, but I don't understand their terminology  e.g. your classpath needs to be fixed etc.

Can anybody tell me how to add a jar file which is imported in code?

**Code**

```
package com.rest.example;

import java.io.File;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import com.infineon.essence_210.api.Component;
    import com.infineon.essence_210.api.EssenceDBMgr;

    @Path("/testEssence") public class HelloWorld {
        @GET
        @Path("/{param}")
        public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg){
            String output = "Welcome to the world of Rest : "+msg;

            Component comp = null;
            File file = new File("C:\\MYFILE.xml");
            try {
                          comp = EssenceDBMgr.getInstance().lookupComponent(file); //<---ISSUE HERE!
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                          e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
        }

    }
```

Error in the eclipse console (cut short but ask if you want all)

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [exampleServlet] in context with
>   path [/RestApi] threw exception
>   [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/xml/bind/marshaller/NamespacePrefixMapper] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2477)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:880)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     at
>   com.infineon.essence.jaxb.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.java:108)
>     at
>   com.infineon.essence.jaxb.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.java:88)
>     at com.infineon.essence_210.api.Essence.unmarshal(Essence.java:201)
>     at com.infineon.essence_210.api.Essence.unmarshal(Essence.java:223)
>     at com.infineon.essence_210.api.Essence.unmarshal(Essence.java:229)
>     at com.infineon.essence_210.api.Essence.(Essence.java:80)     at
>   com.infineon.essence_210.api.EssenceDBMgr.unmarshal(EssenceDBMgr.java:223)
>     at
>   com.infineon.essence_210.api.EssenceDBMgr.lookupComponent(EssenceDBMgr.java:1331)
>     at com.rest.example.HelloWorld.getMsg(HelloWorld.java:23)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:298)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Have you tried to use google? http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-eclipse/

Comment: I did indeed. I add the jars using both the method provioded there and by 'add external jars'. I had no issue with this when adding the jersey jars as the test api worked but then i added another jar, used it in code with no errors and then after running i get errors above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the jar to your `lib` folder of your project. If you want to add the jars to your project simply,

> Right click your project > Build path > Configure Build path > Add
>   External jars

Also based on the console message `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/marshaller/NamespacePrefixMapper`, you are missing the [jaxb-impl-jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbimpl106jar.htm) file.

And you need to have all the jars right under the `lib` folder and don't keep it in the subfolders.

Comment: I did and they added successfully. I did this with the jersey jars with no issue. Then i added my own jars and then used them in code, no issue at code time but then i run it and when i hit my API url i get the above errors. Im really confused as to what iv missed.

Comment: Thx for respionse, I added this but with no luck. What i can see is that this particular jar was in a subb folder, shjould i have all jars in the same folder with no subfolders?

Comment: No if you have `lib` folder you need to place the jar there. Else you need to add the jar as external jars and reference the path to the jar as mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: So what im going to try (again) is to move all my jars into the same lib folder, some of them were previously in subfolders

Comment: that worked man..... That seems crazy considering it allows you to select  jars in subfolders and no errors, no syntax errors and nothing suggesting 'hey you cant have stuff in subfolders under lib'

Comment: if you state that in your answer il mark it as answer - the above was done by me and wasnt the answer.